# ADF : Dynamic content in parameters related to a previous pipeline

Tags: parameter-passing, azure-data-factory

I am trying to pass text with dynamic content as a parameter from a previous pipeline into a Web Activiy on Azure Data Factory.
I want the input of my Web Activity to be a parameter from another pipeline.
I don't want it to be manual like this :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NB2vT.png)

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

You can execute a pipeline from within another pipeline.

So create a "master" pipeline containing a pipeline execution and the web activity.